# Must the domain of gradient, Hessian, Jacobian of a function be open?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function with a closed domain $\text{dom}(f)$.

For example, $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$, $x \in [0, 1]$ or $f(x) = x\log(x), x\in [0, 1], 0\log(0) = 0$.

**My question is very simple: what is the domain of the $\nabla f$ and $\nabla^2 f$ of $f$?**

My confusion arises in that you can only perform differentiation on open sets. Hence, does the domain of $\nabla f$, $\nabla^2 f$, etc. necessarily have to be the interior of $\text{dom}(f)$?

I have not dug up a reference that either confirms or denies this. I would appreciate if anyone can chime in on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have functions which are only differentiable in a single point, though the functions themselves have to be defined in an open neighborhood of that point. So the domain of a derivative function need not be open. An example:

$$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\\
x\mapsto\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This function is only differentiable at $x=0$, so the domain of $\nabla f$ is $\{0\}$.

However, we certainly have that $\operatorname{dom}(\nabla f)\subseteq\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{dom}f)$.